# Excel formula or VBA assistance

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Not sure if this is possible in a formula or if VBA will be needed but I have the below data set,

[image: Dataset]

I'm wanting to take values from A:F, ignore any empty cells and build the value in cell G (including carriage returns after each pair)

I've tried a text join and that gets me a part of the way there but it's makes all the values into one string. As you can see they need to go
A => B
B => C
C => D

but ignore blanks.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,INDEX(FILTER(A1:F1,LEN(A1:F1)>0),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTER(A1:F1,LEN(A1:F1)>0))-1,,1))&" => "&INDEX(FILTER(A1:F1,LEN(A1:F1)>0),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTER(A1:F1,LEN(A1:F1)>0))-1,,2)))
```

By using, `INDEX(FILTER(A1:F1,LEN(A1:F1)>0),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTER(A1:F1,LEN(A1:F1)>0))-1,,1))` and `INDEX(FILTER(A1:F1,LEN(A1:F1)>0),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTER(A1:F1,LEN(A1:F1)>0))-1,,2))`we create two arrays of the non-empty cells one that starts with the first and ends with the second to last and a second that start with the second and ends with the last.

Then we concatenate with the `" => "` and use TEXJOIN to add the line break.

and copy down.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's great. It's all works except the carriage return.

Comment: Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Any idea on why the CHAR(10) doesn't seem to work. It's not issue with the formula as I've noticed it doesn't work in my excel in other formulas as well.

Comment: It's OK, word wrap!

Answer (score 0):

I would solve that as follows:

Introduce a helper line for each data line generating the intermediate result:
T1, T1, T5, T3, T6, T6
, T2, T2, T3l, T3, T7

Rule: "If cell is empty, fill in the predecessor"
A3: =A1
B3: =if(b1="";a1;b1)

In another helper line you can then build the final expression in a cumulative way using vbCrlf for the line breaks:
Rule: "if cell content changes, add another subexpression to the formula, if not repeat the old formula"
b4: =if(b3<>a3;a4 & vbcrlf & a3 & "=>" b3;a4)
...